# Is there a way to do some action if a specific website is visited?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, powershell, cmd.exe, vbscript

I want to make something in *cmd/powershell/vbs* that **monitors your browser activity** and if a **specific website is visited** do something **.**

**Powershell Example:**

```
function Infinite-Detect {
    while($true) {
       $websites = //Browser monitor code
       Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
    }
}

if(websites -eq “https://www.youtube.com/”) {
   Write-Output “I see. You’re going to watch some videos!”
}else {
   // Don’t do anything
} 

Infinite-Detect
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

*I’m currently using **Google Chrome** on a **Windows 10** PC. I would really appreciate if you advice the codes specifically for **Google Chrome.***

Comment: not with PoSh - or anything like it. _however_, you can use a proxy to intercept access and replace it with whatever you want. i presume your firewall could also do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible : The browser works in a sandbox, totally isolated from the
operating system. It cannot launch any program.

Hackers are constantly searching for such a capability, in Chrome or any
other browsers.
Up to now the developers have done a pretty good job of blocking
totally all the possible methods.

Comment: Thanks for the great information!